# Apache Link to PHP run application/x-httpd-php *

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, php7

For example: I create a Link to PHP script *file* to *file.php* `<?php echo 'exaple'; ?>`. When I open *file* online I get the PHP script  not *exaple*. If I open *file.php* I get *exaple*.

I have tried if *.htaccess* works. I made file.html `<?php echo 'exaple'; ?>`. And *.htaccess*:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</IfModule>
```

When I open *file.html* I get *exaple*.

I have tried the same way to get *file* working:

```
   AddType application/x-httpd-php
   AddType application/x-httpd-php *
   AddType application/x-httpd-php file
   AddType application/x-httpd-php ^ (.*)$
   AddType application/x-httpd-php ^ (.*)
   AddType application/x-httpd-php ^ (.)
   AddType application/x-httpd-php ^.
```

No succes. How can I get this runnig?

Comment: I think you should take a look at mod_rewrite. Symlinks are not a very useful approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are [barking up the wrong tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barking_up_the_wrong_tree) with `AddType`.

By the sounds of it you are trying to implement extensionless URLs.

You can do this by simply enabling MultiViews. For example:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Now, when you request `/file` it will serve `/file.php` (or `/file.html`) if it exists. Like "magic".

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html

**OR**, use mod_rewrite to internally rewrite the URL. For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite "/file" to "/file.php"
RewriteRule ^file$ file.php [L]
```

The above rewrites just the specific request URL `/file` to `/file.php`. It does not first check whether `/file.php` exists, so in this respect it is unconditional.

However, exactly how you implement this will depend on your file structure and possibly your existing directives. More generally, to rewrite any request for an extensionless file using mod_rewrite, you would change the above `RewriteRule` to something like:

```
# Internally rewrite "/<something>" to "/<something>.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

The above rewrites any request that does not have, what looks like, a file extension and does not map to a physical directory by appending a `.php` extension.

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

However, MultiViews and mod_rewrite do not necessarily play well together, so if you are using mod_rewrite you should probably disable MultiViews